# How to nominate an already closed StackOverflow question for migration to meta?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

This question on Stack Overflow, [Is Stack Overflow an effective platform for studying programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036437/is-stackoverflow-an-effective-platform-for-studying-programming/1036445#1036445), was closed as "not programming related".

However it's clearly meta (at least I think so). As a StackOverflow user that encounters such a case - what should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flag for moderator attention.

Answer (score 4):

If you have over 3,000 rep, you can vote to close as "Belongs on Meta.StackOverflow.com" or you can send up a moderator flag.

In your case the question was already closed, so the only viable option is the flag for moderator attention.

Comment: The question was already closed.

Comment: @The TXI: I updated my question's subject to reflect the distinction, thanks.

Comment: And I specifically mentioned in my post to flag as moderator in your case. Did you not bother to read the rest of my answer?

Comment: @The TXI: I did, it was just a clarification. Re-reading my first comment it sounds as if I'm passing judgement, which is not the case. Sorry for the misunderstanding.